# Can different order of values in enum between producer schema and kafka schema return 40403

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I am using kafka and spring boot application. I had some issues with the producer not being able to send messages to kafka, was getting

`Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Schema not found; error code: 40403`

As I understand this is not that the schema is not there but I have some differences. The difference was that in the schema on the kafka I had one enum that had one value which was missing in the avro schema in the producer. Now I added that value in the enum but I am still getting the same error.

On the kafka side I have the following:

`enum Test { A, B, C }`

and on the producer side I have the following:

`enum Test { A, C, B }`

Can this be the issue in my scenario?

Comment: What do you mean "Kafka side"? The broker doesn't hold schemas... This isn't exactly a Kafka problem. Have you tried sending your schema directly to the registry api? Have you looked at the server logs? What version of the registry are you using?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I don't get your part: kafka doesn't hold schemas. If I go to the kafka control center then I am able to see the kafka schema of type avro and being backward compatible. It's the one that I used and add it to my consumer. I've been doing this many times.

Comment: @OneCricketeer as I understand my error appears since my producer had differences in the schema (maybe I am pronouncing wrong now) that the kafka is holding up.

Comment: @OneCricketeer as I was suspecting the issue was the order of the values in my enum. I tried with the same order I was able to send kafka message, tried switching the position of one of the values and I got the error above mentioned

Comment: Control Center links to the Confluent Schema Registry. There are no schemas "in Kafka / that topic" , only an ID number... In any case, evolution rules are determine by the Avro spec, not the Registry or Kafka, that's why I said it's not a Kafka problem. The Schema Registry is failing the request before the producer data reaches the broker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change any part of the Avro schema itself, it'll create a new MD5 hash that the registry uses to do a lookup. This is related to [Avro fingerprinting](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.11.1/specification/#schema-fingerprints). When that hash changes, it can no longer "find that subject/schema".

Changing the order of an enum is a backwards compatible change since the schema itself is compatible, but the implementation of the Registry won't accept that change.

You can report bugs at https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/issues

Comment: Btw the answer from kafka guys: This is as designed. The schema text needs to match exactly. You can use use.latest.version=true on the producer to not have to send the exact schema.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "kafka guys" since Schema Registry isn't part of the Apache Kafka project

Comment: These guys: https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/issues